# Cant make a toggle in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make "]" a toggle for when I press "p" its presses "e" 3 times total with 10ms spaces. Then toggle off if I just want to press "t".

I have this but set to "p" just to press "e" 3 times quickly but without a toggle, in case I want to normally type "t".

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetKeyDelay , 10, 10 ; first is delay between keypresses, and second is press duration

; we are using ControlSend here because Send and SendInput is not affected by SetKeyDelay.


p::
ControlSend, , e, A 
ControlSend, , e, A 
ControlSend, , e, A
return,

/::
ExitApp
return,
```

Can I get help on making a toggle?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like to me you're simply looking to toggle the hotkey being enabled.
This is very easily doable with `Suspend`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm)</sup>.

Also, this is false:
*we are using ControlSend here because Send and SendInput is not affected by SetKeyDelay.*
`SetKeyDelay`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm)</sup> works on normal `Send` just fine. You're actually using `SendMode Input`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm)</sup> to change the default sendmode to `SendInput`. That's why it's not working.

I know those first 4 lines are auto-generated when you non-manually create a new ahk file.
It's good to know what they're actually doing.
So don't `ControlSend` unless you actually need to `ControlSend`, switch over to normal `Send`.

Also, your usage of `SetKeyDelay`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm)</sup> is a bit weird there.
It's intended for the ability to add delay to a single command. With your approach you might as well have `Sleep`s there in-between.

Fixed/revised script:

```
SetKeyDelay , 10, 10

p::Send, eee
]::Suspend
/::ExitApp
```